# States in React, how to preserve the original`?

Tags: reactjs, state, spfx

I am working in a SP framework application that read, group and filter data from a list.

To do that I have a method in the app that get called from an onclick eventhandler.

This method contains just a switch to check what other method needs to be called. It looks like this:

```
private _handleRequest(request: string): void {
switch (request) {
  case 'Customer':
  case 'Sales Manager':
    this.groupHandler(request);
    break;
  case 'Agreement Ended':
    this.getEnded();
    break;
  case 'Last Price Adjustment':
    this.getPassed();
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

}

The groupHandler method send a request to Sharepoint that fetchs all the data and then send the data to a ListView component which render it on the screen:

```
private groupHandler(group: string): void {
group = group.replace(/ +/g, "");
this.setState({
  groupByFields: [{
    name: group,
    order: GroupOrder.ascending
  }]
});
```

}
}

The getEnded and getPassed are almost similar, fetch data from sharepoint and filter the result before it is sended to the ListView component.
Each method update the state:

```
private getEnded(): void {

this.props.provider.getEnded().then((listItems: IList[]) => {
  this.setState({
    listItems: listItems
  });
});
```

}

private getPassed(): void {

```
this.props.provider.getPassed().then((listItems: IList[]) => {
  this.setState({
    listItems: listItems
  });
});
```

}

and it is initialize like this:

```
export interface IListState {
```

listItems: IList[];
}

export default class AgreementDatabase extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: IAgreementDatabaseProps) {
    super(props);

```
this.state = {
  listItems: []
};


this.groupHandler = this.groupHandler.bind(this);
```

}

This is the componentDidMount where I populate the state with data fetched from SharePoin List:

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
this.props.provider.getContent().then((listItems: IList[]) => {
  this.setState({
    listItems: listItems
  });
});
```

}

Now the problem is, when I run the app and click on a link that call the groupHandler method the list get grouped without problem. The problem arise when, with the list grouped, I click on a link that call getEnded or getPassed method. In that case the list doesn’t reload before filtering the result. What I get is a grouped list with filtered results.
I post some images to better understanding.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I reset the state so every time I click on a button the app fetch the original state / values before applying filtering or grouping?

Best regards
Americo

Comment: Uhm.. I didn't fully understand: your component fetches data when it's mounted, then you just want to filter that data depending on which button you've clicked? I haven't understood where you retrieve the data that you show in the first image

Comment: That data I fetch in the componentDidMount(). There I call a method that contains the code to send request to the SharePoint list and populate the state with the fetched data. I updated the post with that componentDidMount code.

Comment: Ok, I got that right, then :) Last question to which I need an answer: using `groupHandler()`, `getEnded()`, and `getPassed()`, you just want to filter the items that you've already fetched in `componentDidMount()`, right? You don't fetch any new item, you just "hide" some of the already fetched item. Am I correct? If so, I can give you an example on how to achieve what you want

Comment: on the getEnded and getPassed I want to filter (hide results) that don't match a criteria, ex: if end agreement date is older than today. To get that values I am sending a new rest request to sharepoint with that filter. Now If there is a better way, excelent. Right now are just 2 methods that send requests to SP but it can be more.

Comment: Well, I was thinking more of a change in the `render()` function. I can't see that, but.. Let me add an answer (it's too long to be written in here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I was thinking it's to keep a property `filter` in the state, which is set in `getPassed()` and `getEnded()` methods.
For example, in `getPassed()`, you set `filter = "passed"`; instead, in `getEnded()` you set `filter = "ended"`. Finally, by default, `filter` property could be set to `null`.

Then, in write something like this:

```
/* Inside your Component */
renderPassed = () => {
  const itemToRender = [];

  this.state.listItems.forEach(item => {
    if (item.status === "passed") {
      itemToRender.push(item);
    }
  }

  return itemToRender;
}

renderEnded = () => {
  const itemToRender = [];

  this.state.listItems.forEach(item => {
    if (item.status === "ended") {
      itemToRender.push(item);
    }
  }

  return itemToRender;
}

render() {
  let itemToRender;

  switch (this.state.filter) {
    case "passed": itemToRender = this.renderPassed(); break;
    case "ended": itemToRender = this.renderEnded(); break;
    default: itemToRender = this.state.listItems;
  }

  return <div>{itemToRender}</div>;
}
```

It's really a simplification, but I think you can get my idea.
I don't know you know if one item is passed and/or ended, I just supposed a `status` property in each item.

Does it help? Can it be implemented in your App?

**EDIT:** Notice that I don't "reset" the state. It's not useful since you would have two option to do that:

1. Executing again the fetch;
2. Keep your original data into a property of the class, but then you would have  some items that are repeated in the original data and in the filtered data;

Comment: I am gonna give it a try and comeback with comments. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I added an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found the real problem and it has nothing to do with the state.
In the render method I am using ListView to render the list and in this component I am using the groupByFields property which automatically groups the results:

```
<ListView
        items={this.state.listItems}
        viewFields={this._viewFields}
        groupByFields={this.state.groupByFields}
      />
```

The groups comes from a groupByFields state.

What I really need to do is find the way to deactivate this groupByfield property when I want to filter otherwise it doesn’t matter how I filter or manipulate the state, the result will be always grouped.

Do you know a way to do that? or a way to add this property only when the groupHandler method gets called?

EDIT: I found this solution: 
I call a method called renderList:

```
private _renderList(): any {
if (this.state.filter) {
  return ( <ListView
            items={this.state.filteredListItems}
            viewFields={this._viewFields}
          />)
} else {
  return (<ListView
            items={this.state.originalitems}
            viewFields={this._viewFields}
            groupByFields={this.state.groupByFields}
          />)
}
```

}

And I use state to see if is the filter or the grouping list that should be rendered

Thanks for your time, it helped med to think a little out of the box

Best regards
Americo

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found the real problem and it has nothing to do with the state.
In the render method I am using ListView to render the list and in this component I am using the groupByFields property which automatically groups the results:

```
<ListView
        items={this.state.listItems}
        viewFields={this._viewFields}
        groupByFields={this.state.groupByFields}
      />
```

The groups comes from a groupByFields state.

What I really need to do is find the way to deactivate this groupByfield property when I want to filter otherwise it doesn’t matter how I filter or manipulate the state, the result will be always grouped.

Do you know a way to do that? or a way to add this property only when the 
groupHandler method gets called?

Best regards
Americo